# Multiple value Parameters in SSRS connecting to Teradata returns error

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, teradata

I am connecting to Teradata using SSRS and have multiple parameters, many of them that seek multiple values.

The challenge is all these parameters may not be always filled, sometimes it could be blank. So I am using a logic as below -

```
Select * from Table
Where 
(Param1 in (?) or ? = '')
AND 
(Param2 in (?) or ? = '')
AND 
(Param3 = ? OR ? = '')
```

This gives an error stating Something expected like a Precedes or Exists or In or contains ..........,

Anyone experienced similar issue? Please help.

Comment: Are you actually using question marks in your SQL or is that just an example? Also, was the title supposed to be Teradata instead of Tableau? Have you tried running this query in whatever tool you normally use to connect to the database? The problem might not have anything to do with SSRS.

Comment: "*This gives an error stating Something expected like a Precedes or Exists or In or contains*" Really? Is that the actual error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Teradata but in SQL Server it would be done like this..

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    (ColumnA IN (@Param1) OR ISNULL(@Param1,'')='')
    OR (ColumnB IN (@Param2) OR ISNULL(@Param2,'')='')
```

I've used ISNULL to factor in the possiblity that the parameters are allowed to be NULL in SSRS.